# Facebook API: generate user access_token with permissions

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

**Question in short: how to get Facebook API access_token with permission**

I want to read the reach for specific ad settings from the Facebook API using Python. In order to do so, I need a facebook access token with extended permissions. I use the following function to get a new access token, but the token I get does not have the proper permission levels. So: how to get an access_token with custom permissions, like you can do manually [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)?

Python example below (problem is actually language independent):

```
import requests
import json
from facebookads.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount
from facebookads.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebookads.adobjects.adset import AdSet

app_id = 'xxxx'
app_secret = 'xxxx'
account_id = 'xxxx'

def get_fb_token(app_id, app_secret):
    payload = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials', 
               'client_id': app_id, 
               'client_secret': app_secret,
               }
    file = requests.post('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?', params = payload)

    string = file.content.decode('utf-8')
    json_obj = json.loads(string)  
    return json_obj['access_token']

access_token = get_fb_token(app_id, app_secret)
account = AdAccount(account_id)

# initiate API
FacebookAdsApi.init(app_id, app_secret, access_token)

# Request reach
targeting_spec = {
                'geo_locations': {
                    'countries': ['nl']
                },
            }
fb_params = {
            'currency': 'EUR',
            'optimize_for': AdSet.OptimizationGoal.offsite_conversions,
            'targeting_spec': targeting_spec,
        }
reach_estimate = account.get_reach_estimate(params=fb_params)
```

And the error message I get:

```
(#278) Reading advertisements requires an access token with the extended permission ads_read
```

Help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Step 1: Go read up on the different _types_ of access token. An app access token does not include any permissions, and it is not the right kind of token for this to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @CBroe. How could I request the right access_token, with the correct scoping?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
payload = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials', 
    'client_id': app_id, 
    'client_secret': app_secret,
    'scope': 'ads_read'
}
file = requests.post('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?', params = payload)
```

Also, you need to redirect to the correct endpoint (https://www.facebook.com/v2.xy/dialog/oauth), not POST to it. You cannot get a User token without user interaction.

Comment: Yes, tried this, but that didn't work. Still got the same error `Reading advertisements requires an access token with the extended permission ads_read`.

Comment: oh, i see, you are trying to "post" to the endpoint, you need to redirect to it... i have updated my answer.

Comment: The URL for triggering the login dialog is `https://www.facebook.com/v2.xy/dialog/oauth`, that’s the one you want to redirect to. `/oauth/access_token` is used in the next step, exchanging code for token - but that is a server-side request.

Comment: And `'grant_type': 'client_credentials'` isn’t involved here at all, that’s for requesting an app access token only ;-)